# Why sum of zeta's approaches an integer?

Tags: limits, summation, riemann-zeta

I tried to open my bank term deposits in zeta-functions-amounts (multipled by 1000; 1644.93£, 1202.05£,...) then I realized that the sum of them approaches not only to an integer but also that integer is equal to the last one!
Numerically explained : $s_{10} = \sum_2^{10} \zeta(n) =9.999014...$, $s_{50} = \sum_2^{50} \zeta(n) 49.99999999999999911... $ and so on.
I tried for a while I failed to find out :

Why 1- the sum approaches to an integer, and 2- that integer is $n$ itself in $s_n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that

$$ \sum_{n=2}^{N} \zeta(n)
= \sum_{n=2}^{N} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^n}
= N - 1 + \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \sum_{n=2}^{N}\frac{1}{k^n} $$

and

$$ \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \sum_{n=2}^{N}\frac{1}{k^n}
= \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{1-k^{1-N}}{k(k-1)}
= \underbrace{\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{k-1} - \frac{1}{k} \right)}_{=1} - \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^N(k-1)}. $$

So it follows that

$$ \sum_{n=2}^{N} \zeta(n) = N - \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^N(k-1)}, $$

where the summation part decays at most exponentially fast in $N$.

Comment: You won by a few seconds ! I was just finishing typing the same when your answer came ! Cheers and $+1$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, Thank you! I knew that this question will be highly competitive, so I typed up super quick...

Comment: Super quick is an understatement ! I thought (up to now) that nothing was faster than the light. I was obviously wrong.